# in Mac Terminal I receive: '{PATH}:/tools': not valid identifier

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

Today I tried to run an ifconfig in my terminal and encountered this problem :

```
   Last login: Fri Apr 21 14:10:52 on ttys000
  -bash: export: `{PATH}:/tools': not a valid identifier
  -bash: touch: command not found
   bogon:~ robertmccormick$ ifconfig
  -bash: ifconfig: command not found
```

I've tried https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/bash-command-not-found-for-almost-anything.1072580/   and      https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/help-terminal-wont-run-jar-file.1067170/

when I entered :

```
  /bin/cat ~/.bashrc
```

I get

```
 export PATH="$PATH:/Applications/DevDesktop/drush"
```

Comment: Is OSX systemd based now?

Comment: I'm  looking up what systemd is. It is OSX

Comment: I don't use mac, but you will have either `init script SysV` startup files (e.g. in `/etc/rc.d/stuff`) or you will have `systemd` controlling the system. With `systemd`, the `ip` (e.g. `ip addr`) commands replaces the `ifconfig` commands.

Comment: You got screwed your 1.) bash startup files 2.) and also your network config. Your hostname got resolved to `bogon` thats indicating wrong DNS settings. The `{PATH}:/tools......` line indicating screwed `.profile`.  In other StackExchange server i would say: [edit] the question, and add the result of the `/bin/cat "$HOME/.profile"` - **but this isn't an programming question.**

Comment: what kind of quesiton is this so I can move the post?